# Boost test: #include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp> not found. How to link, config on MAC

Tags: c++, macos, unit-testing, include-path, boost-test

I am new to boost.test library. I have boost downloaded before by MacPorts, and I can locate locally `/usr/local/boost_1_57_0/boost/test/unit_test.hpp`

Then I find an open source, and downloaded the zip folder. The url is here: `https://github.com/jsankey/boost.test-examples`

Then I cd to that download directory and tried to run `make` as the README said, but it threw an error:

```
c++ -omain main.cpp -lboost_unit_test_framework
main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'boost/test/unit_test.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Then I tried to just run one hello.cpp file by

```
g++ -o hello -lboost_unit_test_framework hello.cpp
```

Then it still threw the error:

```
hello.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'boost/test/unit_test.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

The hello.cpp contains a basic test case as follows:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Hello
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

int add(int i, int j)
{
    return i + j;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(universeInOrder)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(add(2, 2) == 5);
}
```

The current Makefile is:

```
TARGETS=main hello suites fixtures assertions

all: $(TARGETS)

test: $(TARGETS) $(addprefix run-,$(TARGETS))

%: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -o$@ $^ -lboost_unit_test_framework

run-%: %
    -./$^ --output_format=XML --log_level=test_suite > $(^)-report.xml

clean:
    rm $(TARGETS) *-report.xml
```

Where did I do wrong, or what I should have done to make it compile please? Thank you so much.

Edit: 
I used `g++ -I/usr/local/boost_1_57_0 -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib hello.cpp -o hello -lboost_unit_test_framework` then it's complaining

```
 ld: library not found for -lboost_unit_test_framework
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
```

I tried to download the boost_unit_test_framework but did not find a source.

Comment: Try including `-I/usr/local/boost_1_57_0` in your compiler flags.

Comment: @bdesham : Hi, I have added the Makefile. I tried to add the -I/usr/local/boost_1_57_0 between $(CXX) and -o$@ $^, but it gave a linker problem. It could not find lboost_unit_test_framework in the makefile. Is that the right place to put it? Could you help please?

Comment: Please update the Makefile showing us where you put the `-I` flag, and please also include the full text of the linker error you are getting.

Comment: @bdesham : Hi, I updated the changes I made at the bottom. Please help to take a look. Thank you.

Comment: You need to pass an `-L` option to the compiler too, to tell it where the Boost libraries are. I’m not sure where they are on your system but hopefully this is enough information for you to go on.

Comment: @bdesham : Hi, are you talking about the include path? I used g++ -I/usr/local/boost_1_57_0 -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib hello.cpp -o hello -lboost_unit_test_framework then it's complaining ld: library not found for -lboost_unit_test_framework
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). I tried to download the boost_unit_test_framework but did not find a source.

Comment: Sorry, I’m not sure what else to suggest. Maybe ask on a Boost-specific forum or mailing list?